# HNF of $\begin{bmatrix}c & 0 \\ 0 & c \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, smith-normal-form, hermite-normal-form

Is there any way to find $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that, given
$a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z},\ a, b, c > 0,\ (a, b, c) = 1$ matrix
$$H = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 0 & z \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
is the Hermite normal form of
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}c & 0 \\ 0 & c \\ a & b \end{bmatrix} ? $$
Note that I'm not looking for an algorithm, but rather for a generic answer, e.g. that heavily uses Bézout's lemma. It will be good if there is some beautiful matrix $U$ such that $U \times A = H$.

Side questions:

1. Is it always true that $z = c$?
2. Smith normal form $D = U \times A \times V$ will be good too.

Comment: With your conditions the Smith Normal Form will have two nonzero entries $1,c$. But surely for the Hermite form we might end up with eg $x=c,y=0,z=1$? [I tried $c=2,a=2,b=3$.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician what I really meant is D will have 1, c on diagonal. Is it true? If so, is there a simple way to prove it? I'm not into this whole theory too much for now.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-multiplication of an $m\times n$ integer matrix $A$ by a unimodular integer matrix $U$ does not change the ideal generates by the $r\times r$ minors of $A$, that is leaves their highest common factor unchanged.

In your example

(i) we have that the HCF of the $1\times 1$ minors of $A$ is $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, and the highest common factor of the $2\times 2$ minors is $\gcd(c^2,ac,bc)=c$.

(ii) we have that the HCF of the $1\times 1$ minors of $H$ is $\gcd(x,y,z)$, and the highest common factor of the $2\times 2$ minors is $\gcd(xz)=xz$.

I don't think more can be said.

With $c=6,a=2,b=3$ in $A$   we get $x=2,y=0,z=3$ in $H$: so we don't get $1,c$ on the "diagonal".